# Как увеличить максимальный размер образа Docker?

Tags: docker, build

наткнулся на похожий вопрос в [другом треде](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45479273/is-there-a-recommended-max-size-limit-for-docker-images-as-good-practice)
однако не нашел ответов на тему того как увеличить максимальный размер докер имеджа, сейчас мой имедж выпирает за 10гб и во время билда показывает left space on device

делал `$ df` и проверил что память на самом диске есть

Comment: Купить новый диск? Это у вас на диске кончилось место.

Comment: если вы запускаете на Windows/Mac, т.е. в виртуально машине, то можно попробовать увеличить размер выделяемый под неё, это находится в настройках Docker Desktop - Resources -> Advanced -> Disk Image Size.

Comment: @AlexeyTen было бы так - не спрашивал бы)

Comment: @ExplodingKitten ssh терминал до убунты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

починил следующим образом

```
$ sudo systemctl stop docker
$ vim /etc/docker/daemon.json
# если его нет, то создаем, иначе просто меняем параметр dm.basesize
{
        "storage-driver": "devicemapper",
        "storage-opts": [
                "dm.basesize=40G"
        ]
}
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
$ sudo systemctl start docker
```